# Juntar varios metodos en un controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Espero poder explicarme bien para que me puedan ayudar. Primero tengo una vista donde tengo que mostrar una serie de datos de una persona (muestro el codigo de la vista un resumen que sirva de  ejemplo para que se pueda entender mejor)

Luego tengo mi controlador donde hay 3 métodos, los cuales me recupera valores para poder llenar la vista. Pero lo que no se como hacer es juntar esos 3 métodos DatosTabajador, RolTabajador, RolEmpleado en el IActionResult verFinal para que cuando acceda a la vista estén todos los datos cargados. Aclaro que no debo hacerlo en en javascript sino en razor c# y es por eso que requiero su ayuda y tambien que lo hago en métodos por separado ya que son varios valores que están en casi 15 tablas diferentes, el código completo de los métodos los omití ya que no es relevante y es muy extenso.

```js
public IActionResult verFinal(int id)
            {
               HCCLS datosGenerales = new HCCLS();   
                          
            }

    
public HCCLS DatosTabajador(int id)
            {
                string error;
                HCCLS datosTrabajador = new HCCLS();
                try
                {
                    using (BDContext db = new BDContext())
                    {
                        datosTrabajador = (from persona in db.Personas                                        
                                            select new HCCLS
                                            {
                                                dato1 = dato.Id,                                            
                                                dato2 = dato.Nombre                                       
                                            }).First();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = ex.Message;
                }
                return datosTrabajador;
            }
     
    public HCCLS RolTabajador(int id)
            {
                string error;
                HCCLS rolTrabajador = new HCCLS();
                try
                {
                    using (BDContext db = new BDContext())
                    {
                        rolTrabajador = (from trabajador in db.Trabajadors
                                         join persona in db.Personas on trabajador.Id equals entidad.Id 
                                         select new HCCLS
                                         {
                                             dato3=dato.Nombre,
                                             dato4=dato.Nombre,
                                             dato5=dato.Nombre == null ? tipoTra.Nombre:orgRol.Nombre

                                         }).First();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    error = ex.Message;
                }
                return rolTrabajador;
            }

    public HCCLS RolEmpleado(int id)
            {
                string error;
                HCCLS rolEmpleado = new HCCLS();
                try
                {
                    using (BDContext db = new BDContext())
                    {
                        rolEmpleado = (from trabajador in db.Trabajadors
                                         join persona in db.Personas on trabajador.Id equals entidad.Id 
                                         select new HCCLS
                                         {
                                             dato6=dato.Nombre,
                                             dato7=dato.Nombre,
                                             dato8=dato.Nombre == null ? tipoTra.Nombre:orgRol.Nombre
                                         }).First();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    error = ex.Message;
                }
                return rolEmpleado;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                @Html.LabelFor(p => p.dato1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(p => p.dato1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-1 mb-4">
          @Html.LabelFor(p => p.dato2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
          @Html.EditorFor(p=>p.dato2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control"} }) 
          </div>         
          <div class="form-group col-md-1 mb-4">
          @Html.LabelFor(p => p.dato8, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
          @Html.EditorFor(p=>p.dato8, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control"} }) 
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar [tuplas](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

```
public IActionResult verFinal(int id)
{
  var datos_trabajador = DatosTabajador(id);   
  var rol_trabajador = RolTabajador(id);  
  var rol_empleador = RolEmpleado(id);   
   return View((datos_trabajador ,rol_trabajador ,rol_empleador )); //notar los doble paréntesis
}
```

Y en la vista

```
@model (Datos.Clases.HCCLS DatosTabajador,Datos.Clases.HCCLS RolTrabajador ,Datos.Clases.HCCLS RolEmpleador)
```

Seguramente vas a necesitar la ruta completa a la clase es decir en vez de colocar (arriba) `HCCLS` tendrás que colocar `WebApplicationMVC.Models.HCCLS`

Y luego solo debes hacer

- model.DatosTabajador
- model.RolTrabajador
- model.RolEmpleador

Según sea el caso

Comment: Gracias por responderme, En mi vista coloque @model Datos.Clases.HCCLS; la parte de poner model.DatosTabajador segun sea el caso no lo entiendo en donde colocarlo, Pordrias darme un ejemplo xfavor

Comment: Edité la respuesta, como está ahí te debería quedar. Recuerda los paréntesis que envuelven todo son importantes. Esta es la nomenclatura de tuplas, cuyo funcionamiento se explica en el enlace que te dejé en la respuesta. En palabras simples, con ellas puedes agrupas otros objetos, por ejemplo 1 entero y 1 un string `(int miEntero, string UnString)`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, queria preguntar si se puede usar la el asp-for con la condicional IF

Comment: Si, puedes hacer @if( condición ) en cualquier parte